# Steam not opening in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, steam

I have never used Ubuntu or any other Linux OS before last Friday. For all I know, I might have installed Ubuntu wrong and be missing a component. I would prefer if you use simplest terminology possible, but I'm OK with doing a bit of googling if need be. I just installed Steam for Ubuntu 16.04 but it won't open when I click on it in the launcher. The icon flashes for a few seconds, stops and then nothing happens. I looked in the system monitor and steam shows up there but ending the process and trying again does nothing. I heard trying to open apps that aren't working through the terminal tells you what the error is so I tried that and I got this:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Please help I just want to play CS:GO again.

Comment: Seems to be a driver issue. What driver are you using and what graphics card do you have? Also I found this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Steam/Troubleshooting#Steam_runtime_issues - It has something to do with the free AMD drivers.. Can you see any other drivers you can choose in "Additional drivers"?

Comment: My crappy little Toshiba laptop has an AMD A4-5000 APU with Radeon HD 8330 integrated graphics. Not very powerful. The only driver in the Additional Drivers menu is the proprietary driver for AMD CPUs. Are there alternative drivers that would work?

Comment: Not sure about that GPU :/ But I would check the link, there are some workarounds.

Comment: It stopped after `assert_20160820112154_1.dmp[8558]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20160820112154_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-3f997128-c49b-4a1f-9f2f-9d7f82160819''
`.

Comment: @Never2MuchPizza on 16.04, for most AMD GPUs you can use the open source driver (the proprietary one has been abandoned), see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Answer (score 158):

This problem is only present at Ubuntu 16.04. In ubuntu 16.10 install `steam:i386` package from Ubuntu's multiverse repository (the repository is enabled by default) and most problems have been fixed. To fix on Ubuntu 16.04:

1. Recommended solution:

   If you just installed Steam then make sure steam is closed and go to `~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` and delete the link `libstdc++.so.6`.

   ```
   rm ~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
   ```

   That's it now it should start without problem. Let it do the update. After the update, if the message is the same (the file will be recreated after first update)then make sure steam is closed and do the same. Also if you have 64bits system go to `~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and delete `libstdc++.so.6`.

   ```
   rm ~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
   rm ~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
   ```
2. In some systems `libstdc++.so.6` keeps getting recreated. If that's your case, then create the script `steam.sh` with executable permissions:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6'
   export DISPLAY=:0
   steam
   ```

   Then change at the steam desktop entry the `Exec=` line at the absolute path of the steam.sh script. Every time you want to play a game, open first steam with the modified desktop entry and then run the game from inside steam. Source: https://wirejungle.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/how-to-fix-broken-steam-linux-client-with-radeon-graphics-driver-workaround/

Comment: It worked! Why was that file causing problems?

Comment: @Goldname Steam uses its own libraries in order to be independent from the system's libraries. However it cannot include everything (like all drivers and more things) and the radeon drivers use the libstdc++.so file which is a newer version not compatible with the version that steam runtime includes. By deleting this file, you make it look for your system's library instead of the one steam runtime has.

Comment: Works for RocketLeague on Ubuntu 16.04, too.

Comment: Works for me. Started the "updating steam..." window. Thanks!

Comment: This worked... but now every time I reboot, steam unpacks itself and requires a re-download of all games and re-verification of Steam Guard.

Comment: @rideoutcolin see this solution, instead https://wirejungle.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/how-to-fix-broken-steam-linux-client-with-radeon-graphics-driver-workaround/. I will upgrade the answer and include it when I will have more time.

Comment: In my case Ubu 16.10, this was not enough as Steam went past issue with drivers but no updates where downloaded. Please look at my comment in similar cases.

Comment: Still not working in 16.10.

Comment: @Enigma Do you see the same errors when you launch it from terminal? See the answer by przemo_li and tell me if that helps.

Comment: That's work for Debian stretch/sid too!

Comment: @ThanosApostolou Yes same `libGL error`s - I had to run the first command from here: https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/412446292752412961/#c412446292752457261

Comment: What is "steam desktop entry"?

Comment: I dragged and dropped the Steam icon from the launcher onto my desktop, then replaced the `Exec=' line as you said, but I get an error saying "there was an error launching the application".

Comment: @arsaKasra I guess you are talking about the 2nd solution. You did right by drugging the file from the launcher just make sure that the script is executable and that you have the right path. Create a `steam.sh` file at your home folder for example with the script as described on the answer. Give it executable permissions (right click on it and check the option that allows it to be executed). Finally change the desktop entry's line to the absolute path: `Exec=/home/$USER/steam.sh`

Comment: I had to go to `cd ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu` instead.

Comment: @Morgoth `~/.steam/steam` should be a symlink to `~/.local/share/Steam`. So, either way it's fine. If you are saying that the folder `~/.steam` doesn't exist at all, then please tell me what version of Ubuntu you are using and how did you install steam (from ubuntu's repositories or form steam's site) so that I can include it in the answer.

Comment: I am on Kubuntu 16.04. I installed off the steam website. The `~/.steam/steam` symlink wasn't there. It seems to be there now. I might have missed it when I first looked, or it may have been set up after I successfully ran steam the first time.

Answer (score 43):

I installed steam with the package in the Ubuntu repositories not the .deb file from steam. Apparently the Ubuntu provided package is modified to work on Ubuntu.

1. Remove the Valve package:

   ```
   sudo apt purge steam-launcher
   ```
2. Delete the repository if it hasn't been removed with the package:

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list
   ```
3. Reload the sources list:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
4. Install Steam from the repos:

   ```
   sudo apt install steam
   ```

For more details see: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/57clur/cant_run_steam_on_ubuntu_1610/

Comment: It works for me on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: I just tried this on Ubuntu 17.10 as well and it works for me.

Comment: Worked for me too

Comment: The same issue also fixed on Elementary OS Loki

Comment: This just worked for me on PopOS (Ubuntu)

Comment: Same thing on 18.04 beta.

Comment: Works for me on 18.04

Answer (score 27):

Try this :

```
cd $HOME/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
cd $HOME/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

Comment: This is the better answer IMO. Note that those paths were incorrect in Mint 18 (16.04). Should be `/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/...` (notice the extra `/steam/` in the path before `/ubuntu12_32`).

Comment: When I first tried this, path was like in your comment, but after fresh install, it is without extra '/steam/'. Why is that?

Comment: Only the first 2 commands worked for me on 17.04, but then steam worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Something that worked for me was to add this environment variable in front of the executable `steam`:

```
env LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam
```

Try to run it in console, see if it works.

If yes, you can edit your **Steam desktop shortcut** to have this command:

```
env LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' /usr/bin/steam %U
```

instead of the old value:

```
/usr/bin/steam %U
```

Likewise, you can update your **CS:GO desktop shortcut** to have this command:

```
env LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam steam://rungameid/730
```

I don't have any idea of what it is doing, but it seems to work for me...

Hope it helps, and I hope that Valve will fix it soon!!

Comment: This one worked for me with Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 3):

## 2019

Steam binary is 32 bits. Recent versions of Nvidia drivers dropped support for 32 bits applications. To fix this on Ubuntu 18.04:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
2. Run `nvidia-settings` and check your Nvidia driver major version. *Mine, for instance, is: NVIDIA Driver Version: 430.26 (so, 430)*
3. `sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-{{MAJOR VERSION NUMBER}}:i386`

For instance, being my Nvidia driver major version 430, my command ended up being `sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-430:i386`

But Steam, seriously, 32 bits....??

Comment: This did not work on Ubuntu 16.04. It gave an error "glXChooseVisual failed". Any idea how to fix it? I am also using nvidia 430 driver.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked for Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

Log posted indicates graphic driver is not installed correctly.

I had a similar problem with fresh install of 16.04
I have reinstalled the graphics driver

first answer on link below Graphics issues after installing Ubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA graphics

Comment: What is the nvidia driver version?

Answer (score 0):

It's solution similar to @Thanos Apostolou, courtesy of ArchLinux wiki:

```
LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/$LIB/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libxcb.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libgpg-error.so' /usr/bin/steam
```

Original solution:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Steam/Troubleshooting#Dynamic_linker

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Solus version of Steam instead of the official (.deb) version fixed this for me.

First, remove the official version:

```
sudo apt purge steam-launcher
```

Then install the Solus version:

```
sudo snap install --edge solus-runtime-gaming
sudo snap install --devmode --edge linux-steam-integration
```

Now start Steam from the dash.

Answer (score 0):

For Gentoo users who have arrived here and want a crude solution, this is what I did.

### Step 1

Removed the offenders:

```
rm -i $(find ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/installed \
    -iname 'libstdc++*' -or -iname 'libgcc_s*')
```

### Step 2

Create a launcher script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_PRELOAD=$(echo /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.2.0/{,32/}{libstdc++.so.6,libgcc_s.so.1})
export DISPLAY=:0
/usr/bin/steam
```

It produces a lot of errors warning about about "wrong ELF class" but I ignore them.  Also, change the path per the version of gcc you've installed.  Feel free to improve (use gcc-config -L, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you think you might be lacking the graphics drivers required to start Steam? If so, and you are using an Nvidia  graphics card, this solution might help you.

If you don't have ubuntu-drivers, then install it with:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install ubuntu-drivers
```

Then check what your device requirements are:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

You will see a number of drivers listed. Choose the recommended driver e.g. `driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free recommended`

Check to see if you have any older Nvidia drivers:

```
apt list -i | grep nvidia
```

E.g. if you're seeing Nvidia 450 drivers, remove with:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-*-450
```

Now you should be ready to install the new drivers:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460
```

If you have any problems, such as a dependency, just add it in the install line e.g.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460 nvidia-kernel-source-460
```

Once complete, reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu 18.04: Once you successfully uninstalled your current Steam (all directory related to steam) please **open a terminal** and type the following in order to have a fresh and clean installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
```

Once you're right the output should be:

> 'multiverse' distribution component enabled for all sources

---

Then install steam (**using the terminal** this is important in order
   to see potential error messages)

```
sudo apt install steam
sudo apt update
```

---

Once the installation is successfull, just type `steam`

```
steam
```

Here either it works and then have fun ! Or you have the following error message:

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
find: ‘/home/$USERNAME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime’: No such file or directory
```

If you do have this message, don't give up and run:

```
mkdir "/home/$USERNAME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime"
```

It should now works !

Comment: For me, reseting steam Every time before start worked for me. Nothing to do with the drivers.
Run command:
```steam --reset```
Then run
```steam```
Login again, and don't close anything. Start the game you want trough steam, not trough shortcuts!
Till this day, I'm doing this each time I want to start steam. But it is a working thing.