# I can not open Steam

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, steam

I'm new to ubuntu. Can you help me with this problem?
I'll talk in comments what information you need from me.

I have typed in terminal `steam`

```
cristi@GIGABYTE-PC:~$ steam 
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I have ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Open a terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and type there `steam` then you can copy the output which gets generated there with (ctrl+shift+c) after you selected it with the mouse, edit your question and paste it into it.

Comment: This is similar to this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/771032/steam-not-opening-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/771507#771507.