# Steam Won't open on ubuntu LTS 16.04.1

Tags: steam

I downloaded Steam off of terminal

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

All went well the game updated then wouldn't open! I ran steam in terminal and this came up

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04.1 64 bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2016-08-09 21:29:46] Startup - updater built Jul 8 2016 21:43:51
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of fail request: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

What do I do? Help please. I used Zorin OS before and ran like a charm. Decided to switch to Ubuntu just to see if there would be a FPS difference in CS:GO. I use the AMD A6 7400K as my APU. I don't have a GPU. Also how do I download my drivers?

Comment: Well, Ubuntu 16.04 does not support AMD GPUs and APUs.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/771032/steam-not-opening-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/818065