# Steam unable to load driver in LXC container

Tags: steam, lxc, mesa

I've been trying to run Steam within a container, but after the initial dependency install, it won't run at all. Trying to run it on terminal gives the following error:

```
$ lxc-attach --clear-env -n steam -- sudo -u ubuntu -i \
>     env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY PULSE_SERVER=$PULSE_SOCKET steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: radeonsi_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Am I supposed to manually install some Mesa dependency?

**PS** It's a machine with AMD APU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked this link ?

[Steam not opening in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771032/steam-not-opening-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

They have the same issue as you do and this is what they suggest:

Steam uses its own libraries in order to be independent from the system's libraries. However it cannot include everything (like all drivers and more things) and the radeon drivers use the libstdc++.so file which is a newer version not compatible with the version that steam runtime includes. By deleting this file, you make it look for your system's library instead of the one steam runtime has.

Try this :

```
cd $HOME/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
cd $HOME/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
```