# Steam won't boot on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, steam

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop some months ago but I haven't been able to make steam work. I installed it from the repos and when I run the app it won't start, if I run it from the command line it seems to run normally, searches for updates and the exits without showing an error. This is the terminal output:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
[2019-03-26 17:07:58] Startup - updater built Feb 18 2019 22:08:53
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2019-03-26 17:07:59] Checking for update on startup
[2019-03-26 17:07:59] Checking for available updates...
[2019-03-26 17:07:59] Downloading manifest: client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2019-03-26 17:08:00] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1550534751, installed version 1550534751
[2019-03-26 17:08:00] Nothing to do
[2019-03-26 17:08:00] Verifying installation...
[2019-03-26 17:08:00] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2019-03-26 17:08:04] Verification complete
```

The only info on the error is this message stored in error.log:

```
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1550534751)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1550534751)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1550534751)
Gtk-Message: 19:22:26.441: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: 19:22:26.442: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"

(steam:17687): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:22:26.446: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(steam:17687): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:22:26.446: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
/usr/share/themes/Arc-Darker/gtk-2.0/main.rc:1090: error: unexpected identifier 'direction', expected character '}'
/usr/share/themes/Arc-Darker/gtk-2.0/apps.rc:91: error: unexpected identifier 'direction', expected character '}'
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1550534751)
[0325/192226.741367:INFO:crash_reporting.cc(242)] Crash reporting enabled for process: browser
[0325/192226.759821:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(281)] Failed to set crash key: UserID with value: 0
[0325/192226.759906:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(281)] Failed to set crash key: BuildID with value: 1550527787
[0325/192226.759914:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(281)] Failed to set crash key: SteamUniverse with value: Public
[0325/192226.759920:WARNING:crash_reporting.cc(281)] Failed to set crash key: Vendor with value: Valve
[0325/192226.766189:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1026)] Lost UI shared context.
crash_20190325192225_1.dmp[17734]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/crash_20190325192225_1.dmp
crash_20190325192225_1.dmp[17734]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
crash_20190325192225_1.dmp[17734]: response: CrashID=bp-3600be94-b17f-4b54-9083-4d1ce2190325
crash_20190325192225_1.dmp[17734]: file ''/tmp/dumps/crash_20190325192225_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-3600be94-b17f-4b54-9083-4d1ce2190325''
/home/user/.steam/steam.sh: line 889: 17687 Bus error
```

I have tried unistalling, purging and reinstalling (as suggested in this post: [Steam won't start on 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038754/steam-wont-start-on-18-04)) and I have the 32 bit versions of both libatk-adaptor and libgail-common.

My GPU is an nvidia GTX 560M and I'm using the nvidia proprietary driver 390.

I have ubuntu gnome 16.04 installed on the same machine and steam works fine there (the nvidia drivers in that installation are 384.130)

Does anybody know what could be causing this error?

Comment: Possibly related:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/548557/how-to-install-gail-and-atk-bridge

Comment: @Terrance I have both i386 libraries installed. Perhaps it's not searching them on the right place? How could I check that?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you could run `sudo ldconfig -v` and see if that helps.  Also try running these two commands:  `/sbin/ldconfig -N -v $(sed 's/:/ /' <<< $LD_LIBRARY_PATH) 2>/dev/null | grep libatk` and `/sbin/ldconfig -N -v $(sed 's/:/ /' <<< $LD_LIBRARY_PATH) 2>/dev/null | grep libgail`  Those should tell you if they are loading.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not ideal, but I solved the issue by reinstalling ubuntu 18.04, installing the nvidia drivers for my card following the second method on this [article](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) and installing Steam from the repositories through the command line (first method from this [article](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-steam-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)).