# After upgrading to 20.04, both RStudio and Steam crash in the exact same way, where do I investigate?

Tags: xubuntu, lenovo, steam, 20.04, rstudio

Upon opening, both RStudio and Steam follow the exact same pattern. They will spend a second or two on my panel, giving the impression that they're opening, Steam will even try to update for a moment, and then they will start to take up about 3GB of RAM and then crash. Steam gives no errors, but RStudio gives a crash report page that contains "rsession crashed with SIGABRT in raise()".

I did try to purge and reinstall Steam, and I also deleted /home/.steam and /home/steam/, and this did work. In fact, it even managed to updated a few times. However, once these updates were done, the above issue returned.

Where can I investigate these issues? What parts of my hardware/software configuration may be relevant? I'm currently running Xubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo S340 Ideapad. I was previously running 19.10.

As requested, `strace steam` is [here](https://pastebin.com/948K1nq8). Opening RStudio in the terminal gives [this incomprehensible output](https://pastebin.com/cPQLs2ab) and `strace rstudio` returns complete madness that is beyond my ability to paste anywhere (it's 12MB).

[Installing the Solus version](https://askubuntu.com/a/1037903/824054) of Steam instead of the official (.deb) version did not fix this problem, nor did any installations of helpful-looking graphics drivers or 32-bit libraries.

UPDATE: The comments from [duckmayr](https://askubuntu.com/users/719126/duckmayr) have fixed RStudio (see the permanent solution [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017886674-Troubleshooting-RStudio-Rendering-Errors), the temporary one didn't work for me) and **this fix suggests that this is a graphical issue**. In support of this claim, I've also discovered that VLC Media Player will play audio files but not video files. If it's any help, my graphics card is an Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake). I believe that it's integrated.

Comment: Please add log for ```
strace steam
```
If `strace` not found, run `apt install strace`

Comment: See new edit to question.

Comment: Regarding RStudio, does switching to software rendering help? (see https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017886674-Troubleshooting-RStudio-Rendering-Errors for instructions and https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-crashing-at-startup/29883/2 for discussion of this in the context of a similar issue)

Comment: @duckmayr Hey, that worked! For whatever reason, the temporary solution (```export RSTUDIO_CHROMIUM_ARGUMENTS="--disable-gpu"
/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/rstudio```) does nothing, but the permanent solution of editing the file in ```~/.config/RStudio/``` worked! Does this suggest something about the source of my issue?

Comment: I think this means that RStudio's default rendering engine is not playing well with the graphics drivers. It's a little beyond my ken, but I'm glad I could point you in the right direction. Got no clue on Steam though ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Although, RStudio's rendering engine is based on Chromium... so maybe Steam's is too? Could be the same underlying issue related to the rendering engine, but I don't know much of anything about Steam, so I couldn't say

Comment: @IvanBorshchov The log is linked in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1876219). Add 'export MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965' to /home/[username]/.profile to fix.

Update: As of August 2023, Ubuntu now has a newer package for Mesa (mentioned in the link above). Using the above fix [now causes many problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1483663/i-know-exactly-which-package-is-causing-me-problems-but-it-must-be-installed-w).