# I can't use Blender, Kdenlive and Shotcut in 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, lts, blender

I bought a new laptop (Dell 3493) and moved my installation disk from my old one. I had in it the 18.04 LTS and after some troubles I decided to update to 20.04 LTS. I got everything to work except those 3 programs, which never start.
This is what I got with Shotcut:

> No appenders associated with category qt.network.ssl
>   [Warning] <> QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
>   No appenders associated with category qt.network.ssl
>   [Warning] <> QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

This is what Kdenlive shows:

> MLT ERROR:
>    "[consumer sdl2_audio ] Failed to initialize SDL: Could not setup connection to PulseAudio"
>
> org.kde.knotifications: Audio notification requested, but sound file from notifyrc file was not found, aborting audio notification
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

And this is what I got from Blender:

> Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

About Kdenlive, when I use the snap version on the official ppa got as well a *Segmentation fault (core dumped)*. I couldn't find proper answers in the web (by the way, I've tried to reinstall an reboot a couple of times those apps).

Comment: Ok, I was considering that. I'm going to create a clean instalation of 19.10 to see if everithing works better. Do you think would be necesary to create a new /home disk as well? I have them separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems not limited to three programs mentioned in the question. According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1239118) it is a bug in mesa drivers.
Adding following line to `.profile` seems let the programs start (I can confirm it for Blender and Kdenlive)

```
MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965
```

However it is not a proper fix and we have to wait for the problem to be solved in drivers.

Answer (score 1):

For kdenlive had the same problem. I resolved it using the appimage from the official web site. Maybe you can do the same with blender and shortcut…

- remove kdenlive
- download appimage from the official website: `wget https://files.kde.org/kdenlive/release/kdenlive-20.04.1b-x86_64.appimage -O ~/Downloads`
- install appimage library: `sudo apt install libappimage0`
- add execution bit to the .appimage file: `chmod +x ~/Downloads/kdenlive-20.04.1b-x86_64.appimage`
- execute the file `~/Downloads/kdenlive-20.04.1b-x86_64.appimage`

Comment: Thanks, I will try! I did as @Nmath said and made a clean installation of Focal Fossa. I got everything working just fine, but I triyed to install some audio packages from the Ubuntu Studio Installer app, and also I installed Virtual Box and Genymotion. After that Kdenlive again got broken (but not Blender or my video reproduction, so it is a good sing). I guess there's some difficulties between Kdenlive and Jack, but we will see.

Comment: UPDATE: about an easy solution to the troubleshouting between Kdenlive and Jack, see here: https://medium.com/@ayubaswad/simple-way-to-fix-kdenlive-no-sound-3923c795788d 
Seems to work for me.