# I know exactly which package is causing me problems, but it must be installed. What are my options?

Tags: package-management, 22.04, xubuntu, vlc, mesa

Both Steam and VLC are broken on my Xubuntu 22.04 LTS machine. VLC gives the simplest error logs.

```bash
$ vlc 'myVideo.AVI' 
VLC media player 3.0.16 Vetinari (revision 3.0.13-8-g41878ff4f2)
[00005555c60eb580] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
libGL error: did not find extension DRI_Mesa version 1
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libEGL fatal: did not find extension DRI_Mesa version 1

QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

After reading [some online discussion](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/solved-recent-mesa-change-in-content-snap-gnome-extension-broke-my-snapcraft-io-build/36265/2), I am confident that [this Mesa package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa) is at fault. However, I obviously can't uninstall my graphics drivers.

What options exist for people in my situation? That is, "a package that I must not uninstall is broken" situations? Currently, I'm thinking of seeing if moving to 23.04 will magically fix the problem, but this seems like an extreme solution for fixing exactly one package.

Comment: For users who are newly encountering this kind of kernel-related issue, rebooting and then selecting an older kernel at GRUB can be an effective workaround.

Comment: Darn. I updated to Xubuntu 23.04 and it didn't fix the issue. I've now broken things for no good reason.

Comment: @user535733 Gave that a shot. Every kernel that I have has the same issue. I've tried 5.4, 5.15, and 6.2.0. I'm now completely out of ideas. Changing kernel didn't fix it and upgrading distro didn't. The only solution left to try is downgrading the package, but that's extremely difficult due to the dependencies.

Comment: Did you load the 32 bit versions (e.g.:  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386,...)?

Comment: @ubfan1 Yes. `apt list --installed` shows `libgl1-mesa-glx/lunar-updates,now 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~23.04.1 i386 [installed]`.

Answer (score 1):

The below does not solve the main problem in the question (what to do when you know exactly which package is the problem), but it does solve the example given (how to fix this Mesa issue).

The Mesa issue is **caused** by using the

> Add '`export MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=i965`' to `/home/[username]/.profile`

fix to fix [this Iris driver](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1876219) bug from Ubuntu 20.04. If you go in to `/home/[username]/.profile` and delete the line mentioned above then the problem will be fixed (presumably after a reboot).

Comment: This was it. Thanks!